# How to create a typed DataTable

Tags: c#, datatable

I created a class derived from DataTable and I want to call a method which is responsible to create my custom DT.

I did:

```
public class MyDataTable : DataTable
{
    public MyDataTable(){
    }

    public void LoadData(){
     //I want to create here the procedure to fill my DT
     //I want to do something like this = new DataTable in order to reference this class later. I know that this is readonly but I think you get the idea
    }

}
```

Then I want to call my new class like this

```
MyDataTable dt = new MyDataTable();
dt.LoadData();
```

And I want that dt contains all the information. So how can I do inside my LoadData to reference to class inside itself?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you access the base class properties and methods?

```
public void LoadData(){
    Rows.Add(...);
}
```

Conceptually, I strongly advise against this approch, a `DataTable` element and a `DataTableFiller` element (represented by your `LoadData` method) should be decoupled in two different classes.

Comment: Thanks! With that simple line you gave all the idea. DataRow dr = this.NewRow(); ...... Rows.Add(dr);